# Paypal gross amount higher than the "fixed_price" I created (via curl)

Tags: curl, paypal, payment, fee

I have created my plan using curl shown in the PayPal developer documentation.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create

This is the plan I created:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer **MY_ACCESS_TOKEN**" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: MWC-SANDBOX-001" \
-d '{
  "product_id": "**MY_PRODUCT_ID**",
  "name": "SANDBOX Membership",
  "description": "SANDBOX Membership Monthly Plan",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "billing_cycles": [
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 1,
      "total_cycles": 999,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "149",
          "currency_code": "PHP"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_preferences": {
    "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
    "setup_fee": {
      "value": "0",
      "currency_code": "PHP"
    },
    "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
    "payment_failure_threshold": 3
  },
  "taxes": {
    "percentage": "12",
    "inclusive": false
  }
}'
```

My intention is to have the user subscribe to this plan with the 149 php fixed price initially and then monthly afterwards.

The issue that I have not figured out why is that when PayPal shows the reciet for the payment (sandbox mode) the Gross amount is higher than the fixed price (149) I have configured in the plan.

[image]

Where could the extra 17.88 have come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to set `"inclusive": false` to `"inclusive": true` instead.

Otherwise, it is adding 12% [on top of](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-taxes) your gross price (as you are seeing).